# cargo build sees my cfg() in the code but not in my Cargo.toml causing unresolved import

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want a dependency that only exists when my special cfg is enabled.

Simple example project: 
main.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    test()
}

#[cfg(my_cfg)]
fn test() {
    use inotify::Inotify;
    println!("my_cfg is enabled")
}

#[cfg(not(my_cfg))]
fn test() {
    println!("my_cfg is not enabled")
}
```

build.rs:

```rust
use std::env;
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MYENV");
    if let Ok(config) = env::var("MYENV"){
        match config.as_str() {
            "my_cfg"=>println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=my_cfg"), 
            _=>{}
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```toml
[package]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[target.'cfg(my_cfg)'.dependencies]
inotify = "0.10.2"
```

when I run:

```sh
cargo run
```

I get my expected output of:

```
"my_cfg is not enabled"
```

But when I run:

```sh
MYENV=my_cfg cargo run
```

I will get an unresolved import 'inotify' error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `inotify`
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |     use inotify::Inotify;
  |         ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `inotify`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `hello` (bin "hello") due to previous error
```

This means that in my main.rs the right version of the test function was selected i.e. my_cfg is enabled. 
But in my Cargo.toml my dependency is not recognized.

When I run cargo build with the --verbose option to see the rustc call I can see the --cfg my_cfg in there.

What is going on here? 
I believe I'm doing this right if I read the documentation: 
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html

edit:

Okay so I have learned I cannot use custom cfgs in Cargo.toml, is there any other way I can change the dependencies from a build.rs file?

Comment: In Cargo.toml you have to use features and optional dependencies which become required by features. There are examples in the the cargo docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how I can do it, I can use the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable to feed custom `cfg` options to dependencies lower down the chain.

So in this case build with the command:

```
RUSTFLAGS="--cfg my_cfg" cargo build
```

And then it works!

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies in the `[target]` table are for [Platform specific dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies) only, not for arbitrary `cfg` values.

> If you want to know which cfg targets are available on your platform, run `rustc --print=cfg` from the command line. If you want to know which `cfg` targets are available for another platform, such as 64-bit Windows, run `rustc --print=cfg --target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.
>
> Unlike in your Rust source code, you cannot use `[target.'cfg(feature = "fancy-feature")'.dependencies]` to add dependencies based on optional features. Use [the `[features]` section instead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html)"

You are limited to the `cfg` options listed by `rustc --print=cfg`.

As the documentation states you can use a feature instead.

Comment: well thats annoying, since my_cfg that I have in mind doesn't work like a feature at all, it pretty much is a target. Its as essential as cfg(windows) or cfg(unix). Making a custom target for this specific purpose seems silly since its just linux minux x11 plus drm

Comment: Jeah I did some testing and features are not going to work either, I cant set them from build.rs either. cargo build --features doesnt work either, I think because this dependency is several layers deep.